# What is the difference between newsequentialid, scope_identity and @@identity?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to make my UserID column a GUID type and I found these three options. I do not know exactly what is the main difference between them.

Comment: If you go with a GUID, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and `@@IDENTITY` are immediately out of question, they both deal with `IDENTITY` columns.

Comment: Also, take a look at the (broken) `OUTPUT` clause for retrieving the server-generated ID.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best version is `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`.

`->@@IDENTITY` returns the last `auto_incremented(identity)` value (even if it is created by a trigger/user defined function).
`->SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the last identity value created (that is not created by a trigger or an udf).
`->NEWSEQUENTIALID()` creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer since Windows was started. (For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)